# Loading a blender animation with textures to three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender, fbx

My question is, what is the ideal loader for loading an animation from Blender in a three.js FBXLoader?

I have an object, material and texture in a blender file. I exported the animation into an FBX, thou the FBXLoader only:

Supports
 - mesh
 - skinning
 - normal / uv

Not Support
 - material
 - texture
 - morph

I really need/want to load files as an FBX with the material and textures. How can I go about this?

Comment: The ideal way would depend on the situation. You can always load the material/textures separately (which I always do)

Comment: You may want to reword and improve your question before it gets flagged as being to broad

Comment: @2pha how is it possible to load a material texture on an FBXLoader if three.js doesn't support that?

Comment: You load your FBX model, then you create an instance of a material and apply it to the mesh